# How to know the source/medium from which user visited my google play store app Url

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

I want to find out from which source user has entered to my google play store App Url. In Google Play Console in User Acquisition -> Acquisition Report where it displays list of Acquisition channels with the number of store listing visitors and first time installers, one of the channel Play Store(Organic) has 2 categories in it 1) Search 2) Explore 
I understand Search represents the category for users who visited by searching from google play store
Whereas I have no idea which category of users represent Explore? Want to know from where in google play store users has explored & found my App? Please help me understand with this information, I have been struggling to understand how numbers in the Explore has drastically come down from last month
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete description of what each section means [is in the help document on the support center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6263332).

> - Play Store (Organic): Unique users who saw your app's store listing by browsing or searching on the Play Store app.
>
>   - Search: Unique users who found your app on Google Play from search results. These users are also counted in the Play Store (Organic) row.
>   - Explore: Unique users who found your app on Google Play but not from search results (for example, browsing a category or similar apps cards). These users are also counted in the Play Store (Organic) row.

So these are users who found your app just by browsing.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, is there a way to know from which category user has browsed into my App Url

Comment: Not as far as I know. I only know what is on that help page.